# Removed ubuntu, how do I now reset the MBR of windows 7 WITHOUT a Windows Repair Disk

Tags: windows-7

I've removed Ubuntu on my laptop as i need the HDD space, and I'm instead putting Ubuntu on my desktop, I removed GRUB not realising it would take me to grub rescue. I've managed to get onto windows 7 using SuperGrub 2, but now I can't fix the windows boot, and it just keeps booting into Grub Rescue, How can i fix my MBR for windows 7 so i don't have to keep going through SuperGrub 2? I'm pretty new, so don't get all technical..
Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Take a look at [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

Comment: I have this, it gives me the error "The boot configuration data store could not be opened. The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5748/how-to-restore-windows-7-mbr-without-a-cd

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart the computer, select windows from GRUB menu.
2. Press Enter to select windows, and immediately start pressing the F8 key multiple times until you get different option for booting
3. Choose the option Repair Your Computer.
4. Click the Next button.
5. Enter any authentication details if any
6. Choose the option Startup Repair from the next window and after the repair finishes,

Now your system will be directly booting to windows