# error no such partition. Grub rescue mode

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I want to remove the ubuntu operating system from my laptop so I formatted the ubuntu drive (previously had dual booting)

But now I run in grub rescue mode. I checked the other forums and tried the set root and set prefix with all the drives but it still shows file system not found.

Can someone help me so that I can normally boot my win 8.1 which is already loaded ?

Comment: You could try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/178596)

Answer (score 2):

You can boot up the Windows install disk and choose Repair Windows option, or you can use a live Ubuntu to do the same thing, like described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader.
Or try this alternate method: [How to restore Windows 7 MBR without a CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5748/how-to-restore-windows-7-mbr-without-a-cd).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It's a magical one click solution for boot related problems.
Grab an Ubuntu live cd/usb, select the `Try Ubuntu` option, verify your internet connection and install the program:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```